# Why was std::isblank added in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I noticed the addition of [std::isblank](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isblank) (in `<locale>`) and [std::isblank](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isblank) (in `<cctype>`) in C++11. I found this [page](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_4.html) which says `Returns true if c is a blank character; that is, a space or a tab.` (for "C" locale), so possibly a blank character is a subset of a whitespace character, however I do not understand the reason for the distinction since we have `std::isspace`. Why was `std::isblank` added to the standard library?

**UPDATE**
According to [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n780.htm), it looks like the POSIX specification was the first to introduce the "blank" character class and then the C and C++ standards followed suit.

Comment: There are two isspace functions. Which are you referring to? [This one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) or [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace)?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: There are two `isblank` functions also.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, they should agree on a character's classification when using the same locale, so it's irrelevant which you talk about. One works with the current locale and the other takes a locale as argument, but they should agree on the character classifications.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> possibly a blank character is a subset of a whitespace character

Definitely a subset. C99 7.4.1.3/2 says, "a standard blank character or is one
of a locale-speciﬁc set of characters for which isspace is true".

It continues with what I think is the motivation: "and that is used to
separate words within a line of text".

`isspace` returns true for some characters that are *not* used to separate words within a line of text. Principally, linebreaks.

Obviously this refers to the `isspace` and `isblank` in `<cctype>`, not the one in `<locale>` as you asked, but I don't think that makes any difference. I don't think the standard really makes it explicit, but the two refer to the same list of "character types".

Comment: +1 I wanted to provide standardese, but I don't have copies of the C standards on hand, only C++. :-P

Answer (score 9):

Both are locale-aware – the differences lie within the rules of each locale, which would be too large a list to enumerate here (assuming there is a single, exhaustive list to begin with).

Of particular interest is the default C locale, for which the behavior is as follows:

- `isspace` returns `true` for space, form feed, line feed, carriage return, horizontal tab, and vertical tab.
- `isblank` returns `true` only for space and horizontal tab.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is simple, it's in C and so for consistency should be in C++ too, as I noted in the [DR](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2019) that added it:

> C99 added `isblank` and `iswblank` to `<locale.h>` but `<locale>` does not provide any equivalent.

The reason I noticed it was missing from C++, and the reason I wanted it added, is that `std::regex_traits<char>` is required to support a `"blank"` character class and so supporting that is much easier if the C99 `isblank` function is available, otherwise the C++ regex implementation needs to somehow identify the "locale-specific set of characters for which `isspace` is true".  Using `isblank` solves the problem.